Non parametric tests for 2 way anova and linear model?
My dissertation is due very soon and I have only just realised a large mistake in my work. I misread the normality test I used, which actually showed non normal data- but I still have homogeneity of variances. I had planned to use two-way anovas to answer the first two hypotheses and a linear model to answer the third. Does anyone know the non-parametric tests I should perform now?
My hypotheses I want to test are:

There will be a difference in species richness between diet types in different levels of deforestation,
There will be a difference in species richness between movement types in different levels of deforestation,
There will be a difference in species richness between groups containing both diet and movement types (ie a terrestrial carnivore vs flying herbivore) in different levels of deforestation.

If it helps, my data is currently laid out like this:
Diet    Locomotion  Deforestation   Richness
C   A   minimal 0
C   A   low 0
C   A   moderate    0
C   A   high    0
C   A   severe  0
C   T   minimal 8
C   T   low 0
C   T   moderate    1
C   T   high    2
C   T   severe  0
C   V   minimal 18
C   V   low 0
C   V   moderate    1
C   V   high    0
C   V   severe  0
H   A   minimal 2
H   A   low 2
H   A   moderate    7
H   A   high    2
H   A   severe  3
H   T   minimal 5
H   T   low 0
H   T   moderate    2
H   T   high    0
H   T   severe  0
H   V   minimal 16
H   V   low 0
H   V   moderate    0
H   V   high    0
H   V   severe  0
O   A   minimal 3
O   A   low 1
O   A   moderate    3
O   A   high    2
O   A   severe  1
O   T   minimal 1
O   T   low 0
O   T   moderate    1
O   T   high    4
O   T   severe  0
O   V   minimal 6
O   V   low 0
O   V   moderate    1
O   V   high    0
O   V   severe  0
or:

Any help at all would be really appreciated, thank you so much in advance!
Edit: here is the residuals data I found, as it does not want to format itself correctly:


ANOVA does not require normal data. It assumes normal errors, which we can approximate by looking at the residuals. But your richness score seems to be an integer, which might be problematic but might not.

Hi Peter, I thought that one of the assumptions of a two way anova is that the sampled should be normally distributed- is this not what a shapiro-wilk test is for? I have just read that anovas can still be used if the sample size is large enough, but I am not sure if mine is.

No, that is not an assumption. Again, the assumption is that the errors are normally distributed. You can do SW test on the residuals, but it's probably better to use a quantile normal plot to examine normality.

Residuals for species richness will not be normally distribution.  The semiparametric generalization of the linear model is semiparametric (ordinal) regression.  See this for resources.  See especially the two-way ANOVA-like proportional odds analysis here.

I have just looked for the residuals of the tests and found this- this is the linear model one:
Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 

-6.2000 -1.4222 -0.4444  1.3778 10.7333
These are the 2 way anovas:
Residuals:
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max
-64.33 -28.13  12.80  15.00 113.87
Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 

-13.733  -3.967   0.000   3.267  18.067
Does this help at all? Do you know what I would need to do with these to see if I can use those tests or not?

I've just edited the main post to give the residuals data as it doesn't seem to format correctly on a comment. Is this any help?

Species richness is typically analyzed with a poison or negative binomial model using the glm() or similar functions in R.  This deals with most issuss of normality of erorrs (aka residuals) and non constant variance. Non parametric methods are not typically used any more by most people publishing in ecology journals.   Most of the basic ideas about ANOVA, ANCOVA, etc apply to the glm() function because almost all standard statistics is based on a linear model(lm)   glm = generalized linear model.  Books by Zuur
